# Conflicting answers when calculating $\oint (2x-y)\,dx + (x+3y)\,dy$ over unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Please point out my stupid error.

edit: $C$ is positively oriented, I should add

First solution (correct one) comes by Green's Theorem. So the integral is just twice the area of the circle: $2\pi$.

Second solution by parameterization. Use $x=\cos(t), y=\sin(t)$ of course.

Then
\begin{align}
& \oint_C (2x-y)\,dx + (x+3y)\,dy \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi} (2\cos(t)-\sin(t))(-\sin(t))\,dt + (\cos(t)+3\sin(t))(\cos(t))\,dt \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi}(1+\cos(t)\sin(t))\,dt = 2\pi.
\end{align}

and no problem now.

Comment: It should be $1+\cos(t)\sin(t)$. I think your error is there.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks.